# Simple example of biopython clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, biopython

I would like get some basic understanding how to use biopython for clustering genes.

Lets say i have genes that i would like to group. How to feed them to the algorithm, and how to give a cutoff point under which size and amount of cluster would depend?

I've tried straightforward approach:

```
from Bio.Cluster import kcluster
list1 = [
    'ADHAMKCAIROSURBANDJVUGLOBALIZATIONANDURBANFANTASIESPLA', 
    'AGGESTAMKTHEARABSTATEANDNEOLIBERALGLOBALIZATIONTHEARAB', 
    'AGGESTAMKTHEARABSTATEANDNEOLIBERALGLOBALIZATIONTHEARAB', 
    'AGGESTAMKTHEARABSTATEANDNEOLIBERALGLOBALIZATIONTHEARAB'
]
list2 = [Seq(gen, IUPAC.extended_protein) for gen in list1]
clusterid, error, nfound = kcluster(list2)
```

but it just brought me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    clusterid, error, nfound = kcluster(list2)
TypeError: data cannot be converted to needed array.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`kcluster`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Cluster.cluster-module.html#kcluster) function takes a data matrix as input and not [`Seq`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Seq.Seq-class.html) instances.

You need to convert your sequences to a matrix and provide that to the [`kcluster`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Cluster.cluster-module.html#kcluster) function.

One way of converting the data to a matrix containing numerical elements only is by using the [`numpy.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) function. It basically translates each letter in a sequence to it's ASCII counterpart.

This creates a 2D array of encoded sequences that the [`kcluster`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Cluster.cluster-module.html#kcluster) function recognized and uses to cluster your sequences.

```
>>> from Bio.Cluster import kcluster
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sequences = [
...     'ADHAMKCAIROSURBANDJVUGLOBALIZATIONANDURBANFANTASIESPLA',
...     'AGGESTAMKTHEARABSTATEANDNEOLIBERALGLOBALIZATIONTHEARAB',
...     'AGGESTAMKTHEARABSTATEANDNEOLIBERALGLOBALIZATIONTHEARAB',
...     'AGGESTAMKTHEARABSTATEANDNEOLIBERALGLOBALIZATIONTHEARAB'
... ]
>>> matrix = np.asarray([np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.uint8) for s in sequences])
>>> clusterid, error, nfound = kcluster(matrix)
>>> print(clusterid)
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks mate, works well. Btw any ideas of how to adjust sensitivity of clustering? and also if i would like to compare sequences that are unequal in size (basically it drops an error), so recommendation would be to add zeroes at the end to equal size?

Comment: @Darius check the documentation of the function linked in the post. It allows you to change a number of parameters which could give you greater sensitivity. If you have unequal sequences, **align them first** using tools like [T-Coffee](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/tcoffee/) for protein sequences. The clustering algorithm does not align, so zeroes would be considered and give you incorrect clusters.

Comment: Thank you  mate :)